Use the linux filesystem to compress files on the fly
I want to upload a lot of data (hundreds of raw pcap files, each 1Gb) to AWS. I am using aws s3 sync for this. The pcap data is highly compressible, but I do not want to do the compression in a first step, wait for it, and then do the upload. Instead I would like the files to be compressed "on the fly", just when they get requested/read by the aws cli for the first time.
Is there some linux/posix filesystem magic that could do something like this? The approach seems novel in the way that it "hides" the compressed files as just a normal file, so any existing tool that can handle files would benefit from this.
I looked at mkfifo, but was not able to find a suitable solution with it.
Why? The goal is to achieve both a higher net upload bandwidth and reduced storage costs on S3.

From the description it's not clear what problem you're trying to solve. Is this about transfer size/speed or storage size at rest?

Both, I'll update the question to make this more obvious.

I found two projects that do just that.

fusecompress is an abandoned project, but seemed to work fine during my quick tests. Supports lzo/bz2/gz/lzma. I found two versions, one written in C (older version, taken from Google Code) and one in C++ (more recent), apparently written by the same person. The latter seems like the one to use.
fuse-zstd is a more recent project that seems to be actively maintained. Uses zstd (fast at both compressing and decompressing, results are almost as good as lzma).

fusecompress seems to use a custom file format which uses more space (I would guess to allow faster random access), while fuse-zstd uses simple zstd files (random access performance may be atrocious?). You should try both out, so you can decide which one works best for you.
Regardless, keep uncompressed backups of your files, just in case.

fuse-zstd looks almost perfect, I just need it the other way around. I need the aws cli to see my original files as compressed files.

A filesystem may compress data internal to the filesystem to save space, but the whole point of a filesystem is that "data you put in is the data you get out".  Your aws s3 sync process would see the original data and not the compressed file.
So you're not going to get anything at the POSIX layer to do this.
You could write a process that runs in the background and uses inotify to detect new files being created and compresses them.  Then your sync process could just look for compressed files.  Or you might be able to write a FUSE filesystem that compresses data as it arrives and use that as an overlay filesystem...
So there are options, but it's not "out of the box".

They would possibly be able to store the files on a ZFS filesystem with high compression (and deduplication) enabled, and then send a snapshot of that to the destination. The downside is that both source and target needs to be ZFS-enabled, obviously, which would be more cumbersome to just compress the files as usual.

We don't know how you upload the file (which tool).
But:

read the manual of your uploading command to see if there is an on-the-fly compressor. For example scp has a -c option that compress on-the-fly;
read the manual of your uploading command to see if there exists a way to upload a file that is read from the standard input, so you may use a compressor like this: gzip -c original_file | uploading_command -specific_option destination_file.


Compression on the fly won't store it in compressed format, correct?

@FlorianBerchtold That depends. In the first solution file, compression will be used only during the transfer. The second solution will store the file compressed.

Agree. In my case, we use aws s3 sync, and AFAIK it does not support any type of hooks or other customization on the files.
